# Hybridization of Oxygen in Orthoboric Acid

Tags: hybridization

[image: Lewis structure]

What should be the hybridization of the oxygen atom?

- A) It should be $\mathrm{sp^2}$ as 1 lone pair must be in the unhybridized orbital for back bonding with boron which has a vacant p-orbital
- B)It should be $\mathrm{sp^3}$ (2bp + 2lp)

(In my book it is given as $\mathrm{sp^3}$ but I cannot find a reason to rule out option A. I am not convinced with option B.)

Comment: If you have mesomeric structures, for a compound, which suggest different hybridisation, then then you have something in between, not any of them.